# How to change persistence layer at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, persistence

I am embarking on a new project and I need some guidance from veteran architects/design pattern gurus!

My new project needs to have a number of persistence layers whereby the client can decide at runtime where the data will be stored, for example, in house SQL database, MS Exchange or Google storage.

The functionality will essentially be the same just the storage/implementation of each will be different.

What I'm not looking for a here is how you do it just a pointer to the best patterns to use to serve my purpose whilst still providing flexibility down the road as their will be CHANGE. I am trying to avoid concrete implementations that will inevitably lead to some nasty code smells.

I know it will involve some kind of DI along the way but any pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special with your case really, so if you would follow standard practices with DI and use container to ease your task like `SimpleInjector` that will do the trick. The main point for you should be to not depend on concrete classes but on abstraction and that's where DI-container will help you organize this.

E.g. if you plan to save user you might have some `IUserRepository` with a method `SaveUser`. Then you will implement `SqlUserRepository`, `GoogleStorageRepository`, etc. The same goes for any other data access layer interface. If you just do that, you will need to configure your DI in a way where you can supply the required repository at a runtime based on your needs. Do not forget to never depend on `GoogleStorageRepository`, etc. directly, but only on a common interface. I would create a project for interfaces (and corresponding BI data model that DL will be aware of) and a project per each implementation as well to separate it even further.

Answer (score 1):

Repository pattern is all about creating a separation between the persistence layer and the business layer.

Many examples on the web demonstrates it incorrectly by just using it as an wrapper over their data entities. That is incorrect. The design of a repository class/interface should be driven by the business requirements and not from how the first data store looks like.

Thus it's a perfect pattern for your use case. You define an repository interface from the business layer perspective and then create an implementation for each data store like MSSQL. I even put that interface in my business layer to further demonstrate that perspective.